# Copy mysql Database structure to another database via shell not working

Tags: mysql, sql, database, structure

I need to copy entire database structure to another newly created database via command prompt or with the help of SQL query only. I am using following command for that -

```
mysqldump -u user -p<password> -d `src_db` | mysql -u user -p<password> -D `target_db`;
```

But I am facing following error -

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to dump your db in an sql file and then import it to the new empty db.

This command will prompt you for the password.

```
mysqldump -u user -p olddb > olddb.sql
mysql -u user -p newdb < olddb.sql
```

Comment: I want to run this as a system command in the program and want to do it directly this way only using single command

Comment: Also the first export and then import commands you gave also throws the same error